# How can I create a symlink to the location that Ubuntu 10.10 mounts a CD?

Tags: 10.10, cd-drive, mountpoint

In Ubuntu 10.10, when I insert a CD or DVD into my optical drive, the system mounts the CD in a folder called /media/XYZ where XYZ is the disk's label.  This has cause problems with Wine, as in order for an application to verify that an application's CD is present, Wine uses a symlinks to point to a mounted CD's folder.  In this case, that folder must be /media/XYZ, but when using a different application, the folder would be different. I would like to know if there is a way to create a symlink that will always point to the mounted folder from a given /dev/cdrom* device, or how to force the system to always mount CDs to the same address (i.e. /media/cdrom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried /etc/fstab yet? For a CD-RW...

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrw
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add a line...

```
/dev/sdc /media/cdrw udf,iso9660 users,noauto,rw 0 0
```

Save and pop in a CD.

Answer (score -1):

Would

```
ln -s /path/to/cd cdrom
```

work for you?

Comment: I don't believe he was asking how to create a symlink.  The question was really about how to either get the the auto-mount to ignore the disk label, or how to have it automatically update a generic symlink.

Comment: Zoredache is correct, I'm sorry if I was unclear.